# Wordpress add_menu_page says file not found

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am making a custom plugin.

For my plugin file I am using

```
require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'includes/functions.php';
```

functions.php is

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_Add_My_Admin_Link' );
// Add a new top level menu link to the ACP
function my_Add_My_Admin_Link()
{
  add_menu_page(
    'My Page', // Title of the page
    'Hello', // Text to show on the menu link
    'manage_options', // Capability requirement to see the link
    'includes/my-first-page.php' // The 'slug' - file to display when clicking the link
);
}
```

and my-first-page.php, which is in the includes directory with functions.php

```
<div class="wrap">
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<p>Welcome</p>
</div>
```

I am able to see the plugin in the admin menu, however when I click on it, I get a "File not found" message.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have not added the callback argument to add_menu_page() function. You need to add the callback function where you will need to include the includes/my-first-page.php path and this will solve the issue. I have added an example below to make it more clear. The fourth argument is for the page slug instead of the path that you have added

```
/*==Register a custom menu page==*/

  function wpdocs_register_my_custom_menu_page(){
    add_menu_page( 
        __( 'Custom Menu Title', 'textdomain' ),
        'custom menu',
        'manage_options',
        'custompage',
        'my_custom_menu_page'
    ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpdocs_register_my_custom_menu_page' );

/*==Display a custom menu page==*/

function my_custom_menu_page(){
    include get_template_directory().'/includes/my-first-page.php';
}
```